# I'd like to transfer edited variables each packages. ssis

Tags: variables, ssis, parent-child, edit

I make two packages, parents and child one.
Each packages have variable the name is strVar. the value of Parents one is "parents". Child one is "child".

I set StrVar at Package Configuration Wizard, and run Execute Package Task Editor. As the result, when child package is called by Execute Package Task Editor at parents package, the value of strVar displayed "parents" by messagebox. I felt it successed.

However, I edited the value of strVar as "edited at child" at child package while the Execute Package Task editor running, the value become "parent" when I checked at Parents package.

the system I want to make is that parent package transfer the value of variables to child package, child package edit the value of variables, and then parents accept the value and edited it again.

How to transfer and edit the value of variables each other?
Do you have any idea?

Comment: You cannot push values back to the parent package. It's been requested but not implemented

Comment: I'm using SSIS 2008. If not implemented, how do programmers do in this case?